# Fluid Simulation as .fbx

Tags: fluid-simulation, .fbx

How to covert Fluid Simulation into shape keys so export it as and .fbx file?

I know that exporting it as .alembic works fine but Unity doesn't support .alembic files for Android Build Projects.

Also for Cloth simulation I can export it as .mdd and then import the .mdd file and i have all the shape keys. This works fine on Cloth but not for Fluid (If i try to export Fluid Sim as .mdd file I get python errors)